# Submit into two tables with single form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

Is There Any way we can submit into two tables in single rails form_for/simple_form_for which both the tables are associated to each other?

Example:-

```
<%= form_for @ob do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.text_field :another_col --> this is another table column(having association)

<%f.button :submit %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: can you explain me a bit

Comment: I have posted an answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to add [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to your parent model, and do as below

#### MODEL

```
class Ob < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo, allow_destroy: true
end
```

#### ERB

```
<%= form_for @ob do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% f.foo do |fo| %>
     <%= fo.text_field :another_col %> <%=# this is another table column(having association)%>
  <% end %>

  <%f.button :submit %>
<%end%>
```

#### CONTROLLER

```
#your params would look like below
params = { ob: {
  name: 'joe', foos_attributes: [
    { another_col: 'Bar' }
  ]
}}
Ob.create(params[:ob])
```